# How to have links with no extensions?

Tags: php

I am really having this Question in my mind and really not getting any answer to it..!
Could anyone please tell me as I am a beginner PHP Developer..I have really worked on some development of scripts but I really need to know how to bind lots of php pages in login system with one another while I know that is done through PHP Session but I really need to know how to have different links of accessing them..!
For Example I have a site it has following files linked to one another through PHP Session but I really need not to expose the file name of the PHP File and also it's directory in public so How would I really call it or visit this as I am doing now like this :

```
http://localhost/script/dashboard.php
http://localhost/script/invoice.php
http://localhost/script/settings.php
```

Instead I want these links like these as :

```
http://localhost/script/dashboard/
http://localhost/script/index=?dashboard
```

Or With Page ID's like :

```
http://localhost/script/page-56/
```

So I really need to know it please..!
Will be great if anyone can answer to it..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's assume this directory structure

[image: Directory structure]

---

Create a file named router.php, this it will be the file that would include all others.

File: **/router.php**

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET['file'] ) ) {

    // Sanitize file name
    $file = preg_replace( '/[^a-z]+/i', '', $_GET['file'] );

    if( $file != '' ) {

        $file_location = './phpfiles/' . $file . '.php';

        if( is_file( $file_location ) ) {

            // Avoid direct access to secure files
            define( '__SECURE_ACCESS__', 1 );

            require_once ( $file_location );
            exit;

        }

    }

}
echo '<h1>Sorry, no such file in here!</h1>';

?>
```

---

You'll need mod rewrite to hide real files location and to remove files extension.

Example URL for settings: http://localhost/script/settings

File: **/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^script/([a-z]+)$ router.php?file=$1 [L,NC]
```

---

These are the basics for the PHP files you've mentioned. Be sure to include that constant check on all those files.

File: **/phpfiles/settings.php**

```
<?php

// No direct access to this file!
defined( '__SECURE_ACCESS__' ) or die( 'Hack attempt!' );

echo '<h3>', $file, '</h3>';
echo '<p>This is the "', $file, '.php" included file!</p>';

?>
```

---

This is to deny access to files in the phpfiles folder

File: **/phpfiles/.htaccess**

```
order deny,allow 
deny from all
```

Comment: Well I need to know Will I Be calling links like this for to access them?
`http://localhost/script/router.php?file=dashboard`
`http://localhost/script/router.php?file=invoice`
`http://localhost/script/router.php?file=settings`

Comment: No, Apache server does it, you and your users don't. 
Your URI's will be like: http://localhost/script/dashboard   http://localhost/script/invoice  http://localhost/script/settings and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You use a [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for that

```
$myLink = "http://localhost/script/dashboard.php";
$myLink = preg_replace('/\.php$/i', '/', $myLink );
echo $myLink;
//http://localhost/script/dashboard/
```

OR

```
$myLink = "http://localhost/script/dashboard.php";
$myLink = preg_replace('%http://localhost/script/(.*?)\.php%i', 'http://localhost/script/index?page=$1', $myLink );
echo $myLink;
//http://localhost/script/index?page=dashboard
```

Comment: Indeed it's perfect..But How would I really be able to access a php file through that link will give me a 404 not found error instead..! cuz file name will be like `someting.php` and I am visiting it with those other links..!

Comment: Use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Some examples at http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: And there is no other way than `mod_rewrite` for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

When a website is referencing a specific page, it uses something like

`http://localhost/script/dashboard.php`.

However if you want the link to be without `mypage.php`, you can do the following.  You can have a directory setup called `dashboard` and have `index.php` inside of it.  See below the following structure.

This is what you have before

```
-script
    -dashboard.php
```

If you want the link to end just in something like `http://localhost/script/dashboard/`

Use a structure like this

```
-scripts (folder)
    -dashboard (folder)
         -index.php
```

Comment: But I really don't want to end up with a directory..I really know that...That's very easy solution..But I really don't need to have a directory for every php file just not to expose it and indeed that's a bad idea cuz Everyone will know then that obviously it's `index.php` file inside that directory..It's not good idea..!

Comment: Although still a thumb up for you..!